# I am using Spatie activity log package. Within my controller, I am trying to pass the item_id but i can get term_id

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

> The event logging for viewing a list happens in the controller. As
> shown below:

> ```
>     if (isset($record)) {
>        $delete =  MultipleTerms::where('item_id', $id)->delete();
>     }
>     foreach ($request->validated()['term_ids'] as $term) {
>         $record = MultipleItemTerms::create(['term_id' => $term,
>             'item_id' => $id]);
>     }
> ```

> ```
>     activity()
>         ->performedOn($record)
>         ->causedBy(auth()->user())
>         ->event('Terms Update')
>         ->log('Terms Updated');
> ```

Comment: The code, as shown will only record the performedOn for the last item in the preceding foreach loop

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.